# How can I remove vertical spacing between columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically it created a vertical spacing in columns which I am struggling to find a way to remove

```
<div


 class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ">
            <h1 class="heading">A Simple database</h1>
            <h2 class="col-7" id="search-section">Search Bar and others</h2>
            <h2 class="col-5" id="result-section">Result</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="data-box" class="col-7">
                <label for="">Search with Serial number   :</label>
                <input type="text" id="search-box" maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter Serial Number">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub">
            </div>
            <div id="result-box" class="col-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i tried to use
margin-bottom= 20px
but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 5x use `g-0` along with the class `row`  ([Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/gutters/#no-gutters))

> The gutters between columns in our predefined grid classes can be
> removed with `.g-0`. This removes the negative margins from `.row` and the
> horizontal padding from all immediate children columns.

Example `class="row g-0"`

For Bootstrap 4x use the class `no-gutters` along with `row`

Example `class="row no-gutters"`

These will remove the column spacing.

Note: All direct children of element with class `row` should have a `col` or `col-*` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property margin-bottom with a value of 0 to remove the vertical spacing between columns in Bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="heading col">A Simple database</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h2 class="col-7" id="search-section">Search Bar and others</h2>
    <h2 class="col-5" id="result-section">Result</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="data-box" class="col-7">
      <label for="">Search with Serial number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="search-box" maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter Serial Number">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub">
    </div>
    <div id="result-box" class="col-5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```